# checking code works in browser

Tags: jquery, if-statement, cross-browser, compatibility

I've been looking into checking some code is compatible with different browsers and using an if statement to identify that it works else do something else.

The code is a background animation effect (which I know does not work in Firefox); i want to identify that the code does not work and put an else statement to ignore it.

I found somewhere that you can just do an `if document.getelementbyId { //code with }else{ //code without`.

My code so far is:

```
if ($(document).animate({'background-position-x'})){

alert ("yes");

}else{

alert ("No");

}
```

and for reference the code that I need to test is:

```
$("#banner").stop().animate({
        'background-position-x' : '-700px',
        'background-position-y' : '-500px'}, 2000
```

The reason for determining it is because it takes 2 seconds to do the animation. If the code is not accepted by the browser for some reason you still have to wait 2 seconds but for nothing. If I can get a browser to determine if the code works with it then I can simply ignore the animation effect and save the user 2 seconds of confused waiting.

Thanks

Comment: This won't work. `animate` returns a jQuery object; it will *never* be a falsy value.

Comment: bummer, is there a way to achieve similar to this or will I have to go through the standard browser checks with if/else per browser?